# Java switch statement "case, default expected"

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a switch statement that prints out different messages based on whether the user inputs a 1, 2, or 3 but I keep getting errors. Just the small snippet of code below throws about a dozen errors which is probably some sort of record for me. :/

```
int menuSelection = keyboard.nextint;

switch 

    case 1: int menuSelection = "1";
        break;

    case 2: int menuSelection = "2";
        break;

    case 3: int menuSelection = "3";
        break;
```

The error message is

> "case, default, or '>' expected"

but I don't know what that means or how to fix it.

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html .

Comment: You need to switch on a variable. something like ```switch(x)```.

Comment: You write switch, but on nothing.

Comment: @Siddhartha even though that is true, it does not explain his error message. If I am not mistaken this code would currently generate a `'(' expected` compiler error, followed by `illegal start of expression`.

Comment: Your downvotes are because you could have more easily goggled the answer to this question than you could have composed it. Google Java switch syntax. Or just the error.

Answer (score 10):

The syntax for your switch statement is incorrect. You need to switch on the variable and also add brackets to enclose your cases:

```
switch (menuSelection) {
case 1:
    break;
case 2:
    break;
case 3:
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the below observations, the switch statement may look like this:

```
int menuSelection = keyboard.nextint;
String menuSelectionDisplay;
switch(menuSelection) 
{
    case 1: 
        menuSelectionDisplay = "1";
        break;

    case 2: 
        menuSelectionDisplay = "2";
        break;

    case 3:
        menuSelectionDisplay = "3";
        break;

    default:
        menuSelectionDisplay = "?";
        break;
}
```

---

Switch statements are required to be surrounded by curly braces {}

It's considered a good idea to have a "default" clause within your switch statement. It acts as a catch-all that gets executed when none of the cases match. In the above example, if the value of menuSelection happened to be 4, the default clause would be executed.

The switch statement takes in one parameter, which is used to determine which case to run. Think of it as a series of if-else statements.

```
int value = 5;
switch(value) 
{
    case 5: System.out.println("Hello!"); break;
    case 6: System.out.println("Bye!"); break;
    default: System.out.println("Huh?"); break;
}
```

is equivalent to this:

```
if(value === 5)
{
    System.out.println("Hello!");
}
else if(value === 6)
{
    System.out.println("Bye!");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Huh?");
}
```

In your cases, you appear to be setting the value of an int to a String. That's invalid; you would need to either

- Set the value of a String to be a String (`String s = "1";`), or
- Set the value of an int to be an int (`int i = 1;`).

Finally, you cannot re-declare a variable's type multiple times within the code (that's having `int menuSelection = keyboard.nextint;` and `int menuSelection = 3;` in the same scope)

Answer (score -2):

```
int menuSelection = keyboard.nextint;
switch (menuSelection) {
    case 1: 
         menuSelection = "1";
        break;
    case 2: 
        menuSelection = "2";
        break;
    case 3: 
        menuSelection = "3";
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: You forgot the parenthesis, the brackets, the parenthesis after `nextInt` method call, `nextInt` != `nextint`, redeclared the int in each case, and did not explain anything.

Comment: Don't provide full code in your answer + it's not even syntax-correct + no explanation whatsoever

Comment: @YassinHajaj @ Jean-François Savard to me it looks like a pseudo-code rather than real code

Comment: You are on the right path, edit the errors in your code.

Comment: @showp1984 this is not how pseudocode must be writtten. And OP is definitely a beginner who needs valid answers